# Updating the datagridview in the 2 Pcs

Tags: c#, observer-pattern

I am starting to program in C# and wanted to know if it is possible to implement observer design patterns in a datagridview?

Where could I start to functionally implement using mysql database as data source?

Comment: could you clarify your question , datagridview is a control , observer is a design pattern, how you want to bind them ?  what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I need to update the information of a datagridview, being that when saving the information should be updated in the two datagridview, I searched some options, Observer, ObservableColletion, IBindList. I could not come up with a conclusion of how to update the datagridview in 2 pcs

Comment: i am sorry, what means 2 pcs ? 2 personal computers

Comment: Exactly, lan computers, where 1 datagriview on each computer and when entering information in the text boxes, the datagridviews of the 2 computers will update, basically as if notified a change in the data and updates everything.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Yes it is possible but there are many ways to going about it.  Can you edit your question to include how _you_ would like to do it.   WCF?  REST? Entity Framework?  Good luck

Comment: Would you have any examples in WCF for studies?

Comment: @IgorCampina if you need a guide about  WCF  , recommend you to use google . I would recommend you to read about Signal R as well

Comment: I slightly reworded your question for readability, but well: I feel it is too broad, and doesn't fit the scope of this community. You should turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask, and improve this question to be in the scope of this community.